# sencha touch accordion list not loading data

Tags: sencha-touch-2, accordion

I can't figure out why my data won't load to my AccordionList element from here:
https://github.com/kawanoshinobu/Ext.ux.AccordionList

I'm creating it within a panel like so:

```
{
    xtype: 'accordionlist',
    store: Ext.create('Rks.store.Bcks'),
    flex: 1
},
```

It calls a store which is defined like so:

```
Ext.define('Rks.store.Bcks', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    requires: ['Rks.model.Bck'],
    config: {
        itemId: 'bks',
        model: 'Rks.model.Bck',
        defaultRootProperty: 'items',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'path/to/ajax',
        },
        autoLoad: false,
        listeners:{
            load: function( me, records, successful, operation, eOpts ){
                console.log("data loaded", records);
            } 
        }
     }
});
```

When I call the view which contains the accordion, the console logs what appears to be a good object:

```
items: [{bck_id:3, author_id:1, title:test, items:[{c_id:2, bck_id:3, title:choice1, leaf:true}]}]
```

But nothing shows up.  The panel is empty and no accordion items show.

However, when I replace the proxy with inline JSON, everything looks fine:

```
Ext.define('Rks.store.Bcks', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    requires: ['Rks.model.Bck'],
    config: {
        itemId: 'bks',
        model: 'Rks.model.Bck',
        defaultRootProperty: 'items',
        root: {
            items: [
                    { bck_id: 1, author_id: 1, title: 'bck1', items: [ {c_id: 1, bck_id: 1, title: 'choice1', leaf: true} ] }
                ]
        }
        autoLoad: false,
        listeners:{
            load: function( me, records, successful, operation, eOpts ){
                 console.log("data loaded", records);
            } 
        }
    }
});
```

Here the items show up in the accordion.  I can't figure out why the second example works and the first doesn't.  Is there something special I should be doing when calling the store proxy for Accordion?

**UPDATE**: I have managed to get the accordion list to display data, but when I change the url of the store and reload it, the store reloads but the accordion list does not update.  The accordion list continues to display the data it receives from the first URL, not from reloads with modified URLS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured this out.  For the accordionlist component, you need to do like so:

```
                var accordionlist = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('rdb #rdb1')[0];
                var brickstore = Ext.getStore('bcs');
                bcs.removeAll();
                bcs.getProxy().setUrl('newurl');
                accordionlist.setStore(bcs);
                accordionlist.load();
```

basically, manually remove all items, set the new url, set the store on the list, then load the list.

Comment: Am also using this way to load new data in to my accordion. Did u felt any slowness when the list grows with more records ? Am facing a big issue my list taking too much time to clear records when i try to clear data using store.removeAll(), Its working great with small number of records. When the list grows with 40 or 60 records its really hangs the app. Please reply your experience

Comment: @Dibish - I actually only use this for 5-10 elements at a time so didn't see any slowness, but that may be due to the length of the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that may be the problem..i have around 200 to 400 records in my list. Using pagination to show that all. So i have to find some other way to fix this issue..

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a problem with your proxy configuration. First, remove the `defaultRootProperty` config (which is out of `proxy` config), then try this:

```
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: (your ajax url),
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items'
        }
    },
```

Comment: I should have mentioned - I tried this already, as well as a lot of other variations.  I just tried again and it produces the same result: I get a result object over the wire: {"items":[{"bck_id":3,"author_id":1,"title":"test","items":[{"c_id":2,"bck_id":3,"title":"choice1","leaf":true}]}]}, but nothing shows in the accordion list

Comment: Not sure about it but can u try 
 {
            xtype: 'accordionlist',
            store: Ext.getStore('storeid'),
            flex: 1
        },

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getStore'